# Cocos2d v3 - Detecting touch without adding the new node as a child

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to convert my game from cocos2d v2.x to v3, and I'm having a hard time figuring out how the new touch mechanism works.

In my project, I have an NSObject (a non cocos2d object). Previously, when I wanted this object to respond to touch events using the cocos2d touch mechanism, I marked it as a CCTargetedTouchDelegate:

```
@interface ControlCenter : NSObject <CCTargetedTouchDelegate>
```

I then added the object to the touch dispatcher:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:NO];
```

and finally used the ccTouch methods to handle the touches.

Now, I understand that in Cocos2d v3 touch handling is different. So let's say I have my current scene (using CCNode), and after adding

```
    self.userInteractionEnabled = true;
    winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] viewSize];
    self.contentSize = winSize;
```

and overriding the touch methods, I am able to handle touches from this scene. I can't get my ControlCenter object to respond to touches though. I changed it to a CCNode, enabled the user interaction flag and set the content size, but without actually adding the object as a child of my current scene, it won't respond to touches.

So, my question is this: Is there a way to make a CCNode respond to touch events without actually adding it as a child of the current scene? Is there a way to directly add it as a responder, like in cocos2d v2?

Comment: Counter-question: why would you want to receive touches on a node that is not in the scene graph? If you need global touch events, just implement them on the scene, and if necessary forward either the touch events or send messages to any object to do the processing.

Comment: Yea, well, back in cocos2d v2 I used NSObjects for general classes that i'm not using as nodes, so I was just wondering if I can do that in v3 as well. Your solution is great though, I think I'll do just that. Thanks!